# Can I put PHP tags within an echo statement in a function?

Tags: php, function, checkbox, echo

```
function addBox($letter) {
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=$letter <?php if(isset($_POST[$letter])) echo "checked"; ?> /> ".$letter." &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
}
```

I'm trying to make a function that makes checkboxes that stay checked even after the form is submitted. The line works fine in html, but doesn't work in PHP. I assume it is having trouble with the PHP tags within an echo statement. But even when I take those tags out, the function still doesn't work. Does anyone know how to incorporate the feature into the function's echo statement?

Comment: No, just concatenate the echo, or break your logic up to be more verbose. This way the guy that comes in after you can tell what you are doing.

Comment: You're already in PHP, you don't need to have `<?php` and `?>` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addBox($letter) {
    $chkBox="";
    $chkBox.="<input type='checkbox' ";
    $chkBox.="name='".$letter."' ";
    $chkBox.=isset($_POST[$letter])?" checked='checked' ":"";
    $chkBox.="/>";
    echo $chkBox;
}
```

Comment: Check this: $_POST[$letter] is missing in the parameter list,

Answer (score 1):

I would advise **never** using `echo` within a function. It just makes debugging more difficult. I'd also suggest removing the dependency on `$_POST`. Instead, try something like this...

```
function addBox($letter, $checked) {
    $safeLetter = htmlspecialchars($letter);
    return sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="%s"%s>%s &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
        $safeLetter, (bool) $checked ? ' checked' : '', $safeLetter);
}
```

then call it like this

```
echo addBox($letter, isset($_POST[$letter]));
```